# Generate Let's Encrypt certificates and set the public pathname

Tags: encryption, nginx, https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm following [the guide to generate the certificates](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutrusty-nginx) and it works well: inside of the public directory (webroot) it creates a folder called `.well-known` containing some stuff in it.

Then it tries to make a request to `my.domain.com/.well-known/...`, but that ends with a 404 due my application architecture.

In my app, the stuff in the public directory is accessible under a specific path: `my.domain.com/!/foo/public/.well-known/...`

How can I tell Let's Encrypt to make the request to that url?

Currently it ends with this error:

```
Requesting root privileges to run certbot...
  /home/ubuntu/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt certonly
    --webroot -w ../preview-app-packed/preview-app/public/ -d preview.mydomain.org
Failed authorization procedure.
preview.mydomain.org (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: Theclient lacks
sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://preview.
mydomain.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/4FH...fsM: "<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR you can't

The fact that you control /.well-known is used to prove your ownership of the domain. That's why you can't change it.

If you can't change your application architecture, you can use a different kind of validation, like a DNS one with another ACME client.

Comment: Ah, I see! In the end I just added another public directory which serves directly the content from there. :-)